# Problems with else in php 7.4

Tags: php

Hi there i'm getting small problem with the second else statment

```
    <?php
 if ($_POST['confirm'] === $language['FRM_PREVIEW']) {
            $tpl_comment->set('PREVIEW', true, true);
            $tpl_comment->set('comment_preview', set_block($language['COMMENT_PREVIEW'], 'center', format_comment($comment) , false));

        } else {
            redirect('index.php?page=torrent-details&id=' . stripslashes($_POST['info_hash']) . '#comments');
            die();

        } else {
            do_sqlquery("UPDATE {$TABLE_PREFIX}comments SET text='$comment', ori_text='$comment' WHERE id='" . $cid . "'", true);
            redirect("index.php?page=torrent-details&id=" . StripSlashes($_POST["info_hash"]) . "#comments");
            die();
        }
?>
```

Comment: you need another `if` condition after the first `else` i.e: `if () elseif () else`

Comment: there is no logic when if use two `else` after `if` condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "small problem"?

Comment: What output are you expecting? What output are you getting instead?

Comment: I'm getting big problem understanding what you're trying to do in your code?